# Corda Enterprise performance test suite - error starting JMeter client

Tags: jmeter, corda

I have downloaded the Corda Enterprise performance test suite , followed the steps mentioned in the [documentation provided](https://docs.corda.r3.com/performance-testing/running-jmeter-corda.html) :

1) Copied the test suite zip in a working directory on both Client and server.

2) Extracted the copy on Client , made changes to jmeter.properties to point to the remote host (The setup has one client and one server).

3) Modified the rmi server config file to have the hostname of the server.

4) Replicated these changes on the server and ran the server, server started successfully.

5) To run the client ran command `java -jar jmeter-corda-4.0-capsule.jar -Xssh node1.mydomain.com -XjmeterProperties jmeter.properties -XserverRmiMappings sample-server-rmi.config`

If we run the command without `-Xssh`, ie. `java -jar jmeter-corda-4.0-capsule.jar` , the client starts successfully , but with `-Xssh` it throws error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'user32': Native library (linux-x86-64/libuser32.so) not found in resource path`

Am I missing some config ? or is there some library missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this one is actually due to not having libuser installed on your machine, I'd take another look at that, maybe try the installer on your machine.

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y libuser
```

source for installation: https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libuser

On a related issue here it's worth mentioning that it's a little easier to run this in Corda 4.4:

```
java -jar jmeter-corda-jar <wrapper arguments> -- <jmeter arguments>
```

Here's the docs page, I hope it helps. https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.4/performance-testing/running-jmeter-corda.html#running-jmeter-corda

Answer (score 0):

While setting up ssh tunnel between client and server, execute below command before executing `ssh-add`

“eval `ssh-agent -s` ” - this will set the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable if not otherwise exported explicitly.

Post setup of tunnel start the client and server.